# Samba permission denied

Tags: permissions, samba, ubuntu-server

Once again samba has completely confused me. I need a share which is accessible (r/w) to only authenticated users. Everyone needs to be able to modify others' files, so I'd prefer to use groups for permissions. When I try to connect from my windows machine or my macbook, it tells me that my account does not have permission to access the share.

The share directory's group is set to users.
The user is in group users.

Whenever I type "groups" or "users" neither the added client user nor the group shows up. I also cannot log in using the account "jonah" which I added to test the samba connectivity.

I have no clue what the problem is and I need to get this done, so here's my smb.conf.

```
#Global
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    netbios name = sambasrv
    server string = Samba Server
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    preferred master = No
    local master = No
    dns proxy = No
    security = User

#Share
[share0]
    path = /mnt/storage/share0
    valid users = jonah
    read only = No
    create mask = 2744
    directory mask = 2744
    browsable = Yes
```

Comment: `create mask = 2744`: you should not use setgid on files (2---), you should not set them executable by default (-7--), and you want to allow write for group (--4-). The correct would be `0664`. For `directory mask`, you want it browseable and writeable by group at least, and browseable by all maybe. It should be `2775`. You should learn a bit about Unix permissions.

Comment: But that's not the only problem, I've just seen you edited. How did you add your user ?

Comment: useradd -c "Jonah" jonah.
I then used smbpasswd to make the password for it with samba. So should I add an Unix password for the account as well?

Comment: I've run the command `smbpasswd -e jonah` and though it said the user is now enabled, after a restart I got the same problem.

Comment: `users` shows the current logged in users, `groups` shows the groups the current user is in. To check your user was added successfully as a unix user, use `getent passwd jonah`. In order to log in to the Linux system with that user, it either need to have a password or to be unlocked (`sudo passwd -f -u jonah`). However it should already work in Samba (if you're sure the permissions are correct, especially the current permission of /mnt/storage/share0, do `ls -l /mnt/storage/share0` to check).

Comment: `ls -l /mnt...` returns `total 0` Does this mean the permissions aren't correctly assigned?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a parameter, it is: `ls -ld /mnt/storage/share0`

Comment: It returns `drwxrwxr-x 2 administrator users 4096 Jul 24 14:41 /mnt/storage/share0` - Do i need to change the owner, bearing in mind more than one person will connect when this is finished?

Comment: It should be correct and you normally don't need to change the owner. But you need to add `@users` to `valid users` in `smb.conf` since it will allow all users from the users group to access the share.